# 0 Have noticed the activity reports v2 api returns updated completions data after a delay may be like a day or 2 or in hours

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api, linked-server

0

Have noticed the activity reports v2 api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/learning/integrations/learning-activity-reports) returns updated completions data after a delay may be like a day or 2. So, just wanted to know what is the expected delay time frame for data sync in linkedin v2 api's.

Was expecting linkedin v2 api documentation to have the expected delay for activity reports api's , unfortunately couldn't find any such information

Was expecting linkedin v2 api documentation to have the expected delay for activity reports api's , unfortunately couldn't find any such information